# How use the insert query using parameters?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010

When i try with this query i get an error says that Perameter email doesn't exist, i am sure that the variables : email, login_pass, payment_method,operateur are valid and exists.

```
SQLQuery2.sql.Text := 'INSERT INTO registered (email,login_pass,payment_method,operateur) VALUES (":email",":login_pass",":payment_method",":avecpuce")';
SQLQuery2.ParamByName('email').AsString := email;
SQLQuery2.ParamByName('login_pass').AsString := login_pass;
SQLQuery2.ParamByName('payment_method').AsString := payment_method;
SQLQuery2.ParamByName('avecpuce').AsString := avecpuce;
SQLQuery2.ExecSQL(true);
```

I tried removing the quotation, but i get

> You have an error in your Sql syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your SQL server for the right syntax to use near
>   ':email,:login_pass,:payment_method,:avecpuce)' at line 1

How to use the insert query above using parameters?

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to? Is it MySql, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: What type is SQLQuery2 - is it a TQuery or a TADOQuery?

Comment: not Tquery nor Tadoquery  it's TSQLQuery. @codeulike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer !

```
MySQLQuery2.SQL.Clear;
MySQLQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO COUNTRY (NAME, CAPITAL, POPULATION)');
MySQLQuery2.SQL.Add('VALUES (:Name, :Capital, :Population)');
MySQLQuery2.Params[0].AsString := 'Lichtenstein';
MySQLQuery2.Params[1].AsString := 'Vaduz';
MySQLQuery2.Params[2].AsInteger := 420000;
MySQLQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

Thankyou All !!

Comment: your answer is my answer :) glad I could help

Comment: You would have saved yourself a day if you've read mjn's answer, and also would have saved the trouble posting an answer yourself.

Comment: mjn answer didn't work for me, the problem wasn't only because of the execSQL but also in the query string it self which shouldn't be as i mentioned in my answer but should be entred by using MySQLQuery.SQL.Add .  Thankyou for mjn post for help with the execSQL true or false issue.

Comment: @Rafik Bari: SQLQuery2.sql.Text := ... and SQLQuery2.sql.Clear; ... SQL.Add both do the same.

Comment: Ok! Thankyou anyway your answer also helped me too much!

Answer (score 7):

From the [TSQLQuery.ExecSQL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.ExecSQL) documentation:

> ExecDirect indicates that the query does not need to be prepared
>   before it is executed. This parameter can be set to true if the query
>   does not include any parameters.

So if the code uses

```
SQLQuery2.ExecSQL(true);
```

this means that there will be no support for parameters.

But because you use parameters, just use

```
SQLQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

and also remove the quotes around parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Remove quotation marks:

```
SQLQuery2.sql.Text := 'INSERT INTO registered (email,login_pass,payment_method,operateur)
   VALUES (:email, :login_pass, :payment_method, :avecpuce)';
```

Comment: You have an error in your Sql syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your SQL server for the right syntax to use near ':email,:login_pass,:payment_method,:avecpuce)' at line 1

Comment: SQL syntax is perfect (I am using Firebird). I can only guess what is wrong in your case, may be you should use a different symbol as a parameter prefix ('?' or '@' instead of ':').

Comment: Yep, that corrected the syntax problem, but i still get an error EDatabase Error 'SQLQuery2: parameter 'email' not found'

Comment: that is the same error when i use quotations.Thankyou for ure reply !

Answer (score 3):

You don't usually quote parameters, only literals.  So instead of:

```
VALUES (":email",":login_pass",":payment_method",":avecpuce")
```

Try:

```
VALUES (:email,:login_pass,:payment_method,:avecpuce)
```

Comment: You have an error in your Sql syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your SQL server for the right syntax to use near ':email,:login_pass,:payment_method,:avecpuce)' at line 1

Comment: That's strange, check if there is unusual whitespace characters? (Retype the query manually, without copy/paste)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use quotes around the parameter name.

Parameters are automatically generated for you if your TSQLQuery has a connection assigned and ParamCheck is true and you assign TSQLQuery.CommandText.

It will not generate the parameters when you assign the query to TSQLQuery.SQL.Text.

You can have the parameters generated for you by calling TSQLQuery.Params.ParseSQL:

```
SQLQuery2.Params.ParseSQL(SQLQuery2.SQL.Text, True);
```

Or you can add them yourself by calling TSQLQuery.Params.AddParameter.