# How to insert real values into a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm trying to insert values into the MedicationPrices table with the following code.

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddMedicineClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 sMedication, sQuantity : string;
 rPrice : real;
begin
sMedication := InputBox('Add Medication','Please enter the medications name','');
sQuantity := InputBox('Add Medication','Please enter the the quantity','');
rPrice := StrToFloat(InputBox('Add Medication','Please enter the the price',''));

with dmHospital do
begin
  qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
  qryPrices.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO MedicationPrices (Medication, Quantity)');
  qryPrices.SQL.Add('VALUES(' + QuotedStr(sMedication) +',' + QuotedStr(sQuantity)  + ' )');
  qryPrices.Parameters.ParamByName('Price').Value := rPrice;
  qryPrices.ExecSQL;
  qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
  qryPrices.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * MedicationPrices ';
  qryPrices.Open;
end;
end;
```

However it and a few different variations just don't work. I get:
[image: Error message]

I don't understand why it doesn't see 'Price' as it is clearly in the table.
[image: Design view of table]

Comment: I think you were missing the difference between a column (aka field) name and a query parameter.  They are **not** the same thing.

Comment: I would hate to find myself at this hospital :-/

Comment: with..do should be banned forever imo

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks for your vote of confidence. Luckily it's not for a real hospital.

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Why? It makes coding shorter and therefore quicker.

Comment: `with...do` is somewhat dangerous when you use it in situations where identifiers in this block won't be unique anymore. It shouldn't be used.

Comment: Just what @RenéHoffmann said. In this case it could be handy but if you keep using it with more than one object/component, the code becomes a mess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add the parameters in your query (line with VALUES).

Then when you use the `ParamByName` function, it will basically **replace** the parameter (`:Price`) from the query by the value that you set (`rPrice`).

Example of correction:

```
with dmHospital do
begin
  qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
  qryPrices.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO MedicationPrices (Medication, Quantity, Price)');
  qryPrices.SQL.Add('VALUES(:Medication, :Quantity, :Price)');
  qryPrices.Parameters.ParamByName('Medication').Value := sMedication;
  qryPrices.Parameters.ParamByName('Quantity').Value := sQuantity;
  qryPrices.Parameters.ParamByName('Price').Value := rPrice;
  qryPrices.ExecSQL;
  qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
  qryPrices.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MedicationPrices ';
  qryPrices.Open;
end;
```

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667747/how-use-the-insert-query-using-parameters) about parameters in Delphi in INSERT.

Comment: Looks like there is a FROM missing from your SELECT statement.

Comment: Good catch @MartynA, I did not check the rest of the code. I just edited my answer ;-)

Comment: @brclz Thanks for your answer but i still get the same error message but with ':Medication' instead.

Comment: @OceanKnight: True! The syntax was a bit wrong, its `ParamByName('PARAMETER_NAME').Value` without the two dots. I updated it.